# How to use codeartifact repo in aws lambda function?

Tags: aws-lambda

I tried creating a layer for the repo but it exceeds the size limit, and the project doesn't use Docker. Is there any other way to install the dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up a layer with all the dependencies installed in Amazon Linux 2. In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6rh4YzhrTg&t=245s&ab_channel=AmazonWebServices) there is a step by step.